# Disappearing electron

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, double-slit-experiment, interference, superposition

I'm sure the answer to this question will be 'no', but I'd really like to understand why/why not.

Say a single electron is sent towards a double slit. Some people talk of it 'going through both slits at the same time and interfering with itself'. If it interferes with itself in a destructive way, can the electron disappear?

Comment: How would you then account for charge conservation?

Answer (score 3):

> If it interferes with itself in a destructive way, can the electron disappear?

No. The wave function is related to the probability of the electron being detected at a given location. So where you get destructive interference you get a local region where the probability of finding the electron goes to zero. However, because of the way the math works, the destructive interference in one location is always associated with constructive interference in another location such that the probability of finding the electron somewhere is always 1.

Comment: Is this 'mulitilocation' thing because it's treated as a wave packet?

Comment: It is part of the way that we define the wave function. It is always normalized so that there is a unit probability of finding it somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [the crude analogy of water waves](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/237552/45786), your question is like asking whether a water wave can disappear if it passes through 2 slits and undergoes destructive interference. The point is that destructive interference only means that at certain points the wave has zero displacement, not that it disappears. Similarly, at certain points the wavefunction of a particle in an ideal 2-slit experiment would have zero value, but the wavefunction does not disappear...