# Can a particle accelerator create UFOs?

Tags: particle-physics

[Someone theorized on their blog](https://www.otherhand.org/home-page/area-51-and-other-strange-places/so-ya-dont-believe-it-was-a-proton-beam-eh/), that if you would direct a 500 MeV proton beam into just air, it would create a glowing ball about 1.2 km from the target, with nothing inbetween. They theorized that this could be used to create glowing balls which can be mistaken for UFOs, because the plasma ball could move very fast through the air by just shifting the proton beam with magnets.

While I understand, that the energy deposition of a proton beam would have their maximum at a certain distance, due to the Bragg peak, I doubt that the beam would not significantly ionize air molecules inbetween and would thus be visible as a ray between the source of the beam and the plasma ball.

Would this be the case? Would the beam be visible in all circumstances?

Comment: Voting to close. Far fetched mechanisms that might explain UFOs are not main-stream physics.

Comment: Well, external, MeV-range alpha beams do create a nice blue glow from ionizing nitrogen (primarily). But, it is only a few cm in length (one of the ways Rutherford/Geiger/Marsden estimated alpha particle energies was by the blue glow in air). You should do a back-of-the-envelope calculation of the range, in air, of a 500MeV proton beam. And, yes, it will be losing energy along the way (electronic stopping - the ionization). The Bragg peak is for nuclear stopping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there were no air, the proton beam would go to infinity if pointed at the sky. The reason there is a given distance for  given energy beams is the ionization loss of the individual protons in the beam as they travel through air: the protons ionize the medium. This will give  some visible frequency photons close to the stopping point, depending on the density of the beam, and possibly on the way to the stopping point.

To get an idea of beam behavior in a substance see [fig 6b in this paper .](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1608/1608.02476.pdf)  For protons in air one would have to do a simulation, and see how much power there is in the visible for a particular density beam.

For example bubble chamber pictures work on the ionization loss of the charged particles in the medium, making small  bubbles. The loss is small, because it is very seldom that an electron is ejected on the path of a charged particle(  see the [picture here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/237350/why-cant-an-electron-be-observed/237363#237363) ).

[In this publication](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/24387491/) the path of other beams in air is explored.

> Conclusions: Air scintillation can be measured to monitor a radiation beam in an inexpensive and nonperturbing manner. ...

So that the beam would only show at end point is not true. If it is dense enough to produce a light ball at the stopping point it will be dense enough to be seen on the way as light.