# What happens to the wave function after it collapses?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, observables, wavefunction-collapse

If a quantum particle is described by a certain wave function and we express it as superposition of for example its possibles energy states, after we measure it the wave function collapses and we observe the quantum particle as having a certain energy. I have a couple questions.

1. No matter what happens to that particle or what I do with it everytime that I observe it again it's going to be in that same energy state?
2. If after measuring energy I now try to measure something else like position could the energy state change when I measure it again?

In general I'm trying to understand what it means that the wave function collapses because by what I've studied it sounds like it's undoable but that doesn't make much sense to me. So far I thought that when we observe a particle's energy for example we measure a certain energy but then if we measure it again right after we could measure any of the other possible energy states but I'm told this is wrong. How does it actually work then?

Comment: This has been addressed here somehow: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/612051/how-precisely-can-particle-position-be-measured-in-a-laboratory/612068#612068

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> No matter what happens to that particle or what I do with it every time that I observe it again it's going to be in that same energy state ?

No, not necessarily. After it has collapsed into an eigenstate, the particle's wave function will then evolve in accordance with the Schrodinger equation. A subsequent measurement of the same attribute could result in collapse into a different eigenstate and hence a different measured value.

> If we measure it again right after we could measure any of the other possible energy states ...

If the time interval between the two measurements is very short then the wave function has not had time to change by much, and it is very likely that the second measurement will give the same result as the first. However, for any non-zero time interval, there will always be a non-zero probability (albeit a very small probability) that the second measurement will collapse the wave function into a different eigenstate and give a different result.

> If after measuring energy I now try to measure something else like position could the energy state change when I measure it again ?

Yes, definitely. It is likely that position eigenstates are not the same as energy eigenstates, so a position eigenstate will be a superposition of multiple energy eigenstates.

> ... it sounds like it (wave function collapse) is undoable ...

Depends on what you mean by "undoable". Wave function collapse is *irreversible*, because information about the original wave function is lost in the collapse (unless you use the many worlds interpretation of QM, in which case information is not exactly lost, but is at least irretrievable).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! One final question, after the wave function first collapses and I measure the energy of the particle again are the probabilities of measuring the different energy states the same as they were in the initial wave function? Or does the fact that I have measured it change the original probabilities?

Comment: @Omeglac The probability of a given result from a  measurement depends on the shape of the wave function when the measurement is made. When the wave function collapses its shape changes, so the probability distribution changes.